# Hiding character in edittext

Tags: android

I have the following code

```
public class Answer extends Activity  implements KeyListener{
EditText ed1;
Button b;
LinearLayout l;
int flag=0;
int f=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.answer);
ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ans);
l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.An);
ed1.setKeyListener(this);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag==1)
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
});


}
    public boolean onKeyUp(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg2){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
        if(f==0){
            ed1.setText("");
            f++;
            flag=1;
        }

    }
    return false;
    }
```

The problem with this code is that on pressing 'a' it is setting color but after that it doesn't show anything in the edittext - ie it is setting color but after that it is not showing anything in edittext.If we press 'a' followed by 'n' then it will hide both 'a' and 'n' but i want to hide 'a' only

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove all of the a's from your EditText every time that you type 'a', then `ed1.setText("");` is the culprit (it's clearing your EditText value every time).

Try this edit in your switch case:

```
String currText = ed1.getText().toString();
ed1.setText(currText.replace("a", ""));
```

Comment: He should also consider to use a [TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(Editable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) instead of the KeyListener.

Comment: I dont want to remove all the a's.only the first one

Comment: Then try: `ed1.setText(currText.replaceFirst("(.*)a(.*)", "");`  This will replace the first instance of "a" in your string, using regex.